# Positions overlap when browser window is minimized

Tags: joomla2.5

I hope someone can help.

I have started to build a website for a client using JA Brisk template. I notice when the width of the browser window is reduced, the content in the positions start overlapping (instead of keeping the same dimensions and introducing a horizontal scroll bar, which is what happens with the sites I developed in 2.5.9). I am wondering if this has something to do with the wrapper settings in BJA Brisk?

My website can be viewed here - http://edrivenmedic.com/
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You are using a responsive template. I'm not familiar with your JA Brisk template or the T3 framework specifically, but often with responsive sites one thing you need to avoid is setting image sizes. Instead you rely on the framework CSS to size the images relative to their container.

If the overlapping issue you refer to is with the four blocks under the carousel on the home page try removing image dimensions for the smartphone/iPhone/iPad images.

Good luck!